# PHP is not working on Ubuntu Apache server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I just installed php and apache server on Ubuntu 17.04 but my `.php` file doesn't work on my browser.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<?php
  echo "Hello World!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Only `Welcome!` appeared on the browser, and when I inspect the page I see php code is being commented. I have already started apache server and still have no idea what is wrong. Please help me out, thank you!

`$ php -v`

```
PHP 7.0.15-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2017 21:33:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-1ubuntu4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status`

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-04-25 14:38:55 +07; 10min ago
  Process: 11578 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11604 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11619 (apache2)
    Tasks: 55 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 9.7M
      CPU: 429ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─11619 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─11663 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─11664 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 25 14:38:55 g5080 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 25 14:38:55 g5080 apachectl[11604]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determin…sage
Apr 25 14:38:55 g5080 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: how do you open the file, i mean the url ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @bfahmi localhost/, cuz I named the file `index.php`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

while you are in ubuntu 17.04

you can follow this steps

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php7.0 mysql-server php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring phpmyadmin     //install
sudo service apache2 restart    //restart
```

and give it another try for your file(index.php)

Comment: `a2query -m php7.0` returns `No module matches php7.0`

Comment: try a2query -m php

Comment: I still get `No module matches php`

Comment: @HuyVo check the response

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me :)

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4 php-mbstring php7.4-mbstring      this command save my life.

Answer (score 6):

Check the below configuration in your web server

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5`
```

It will install everything you need and will start the apache server with support for PHP.

To verify that the php module is loaded, type:

```
   a2query -m php5
```

if not enabled, then load with:

```
   sudo a2enmod php5
```

and restart apache:

```
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.04, so `libapache2-mod-php5` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using 18.04 and used sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6 to install. it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Trying this command actually worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-curl php-gd php-pear php-imagick php-imap php-mcrypt php-recode php-tidy php-xmlrpc
```

Answer (score 2):

> Tested Fixture for AWS Ubuntu 18.04

Step 1 - In AWS Server,  have created Ubuntu 18.04, connect via putty, search for apache2.conf file.
Step 2 - With apache2.conf open in the directory [`$ sudo vi apache2.conf`], press `I` for editing file, all you have to do is add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
​SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
​</FilesMatch>
```

Save and close apache2.conf.
Step 3 (usually not needed) -
Enable/disable modules
In order to get PHP to function properly, you have to disable the mpm_event module and enable the mpm_prefork and php7 modules. To do this, go back to your terminal window and issue the command:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event && sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork && sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

Step 4 - Restart Apache 2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20 too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a special case:
I wanted to directly call a php file inside a subdirectory of "/var/www/**vhosts**/.../somePage/index.php" (after restoring from an old VM).
It wasn't possible, the index.php would just be downloaded
After moving the ".../somePage/" directory from "/var/www/vhosts/..." to "/var/www/" the index.php would run correctly (calling http://localhost/somedir/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Package php-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
this error comes after giving the command
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-curl php-gd php-pear php-imagick php-imap php-mcrypt php-recode php-tidy php-xmlrpc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2023: Works with Rasbian Debian Bullseye and Debian Bookworm.

You need to edit file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and add to the end of file:

```ini
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

Then reload `apache2.service` with:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Then check if service is correctly loaded with:

```bash
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```